# Correct way to import modern React into WordPress theme?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

What is the proper way of importing React JS in the WordPress theme?

Does this mean how to turn on a live Apache live server and NodeJS local?

Do both sides have to be separate or can they be in one? What should the folder structure look like?

I don't want to import a React CDN's I want to have a powerful environment in how `create-react-app` can offer.  Like react-router, like Redux and all modern React ecosystem.
Is this possible?

Thanks, o/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use a modern react-based front-end framework together with the the wordpress' back office which most of the content editors familiar with, I recommend to use GatsbyJs with [gatsby-source-wordpress](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/) plugin.

However you can simply use react inline within an html page. You need a root div where the react handles the DOM, while outside of this div you can use whatever you want. If you want more than one react-controlled div within one page, it is a bit more complicated though.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        checked={checked}
      />
      <span>Hello in {checked ? 'react' : 'wordpress'} world</span>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div>This is the non-react part of the page</div>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I think you don't understand me, the point of my question is to correct way connecting react and WordPress, eg.  how to replace jQuery to React, for handlers, for example...